# Check if a list of urls exist or not in bash with curl

Tags: bash, curl, syntax-error

I'm trying to check if a list of urls are valid or not. I'm trying this Bash but I'm no getting the correct syntax.

```
for url in $(cat domains.txt) 
do curl --output /dev/null --silent --head --fail "$url"; then
  echo "URL exists: $url"
else
  echo "URL does not exist: $url"
done
```

Can anyone give me a hand?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

you're missing an `if` (and corresponding `fi`) to make your code work.

```
#!/bin/bash
for url in $(cat domains.txt) 
do 
  if curl --output /dev/null --silent --head --fail "$url"; then
    echo "URL exists: $url"
  else
    echo "URL does not exist: $url"
  fi 
done
```

Comment: Check [Don't Read Files with For](https://mywiki.wooledge.org/DontReadLinesWithFor).

Answer (score 1):

You can also can make that the script check each url and if it's a redirection , give you the redirected url:

```
#!/bin/bash
for URL in $(cat urls.txt) ; do 
res="$(curl --silent --head --location --output /dev/null --write-out '%{http_code}'  $URL | grep '^2')"
if [[ $res == 200 ]]; then
curl -s -L -I -o /dev/null -w $URL' -> %{url_effective}\n' $URL;
else
echo "$URL -> "does not exist""
fi 
done
```

`